# call different service on the basis of string parameter in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my controller, I receive a string parameter on the basis of which I need to decide which service to call, how can I do the same in my Spring Boot application using Spring annotations?

For example: we have different types of cars. Now, on the basis of parameter in the request I should be able to decide which particular car service I should call.

How can I have a factory using annotations in Spring Boot, and objects should be returned from that factory on the basis of input.

Comment: What have you tried? What concrete problem are you facing?

Comment: the question was asked to me in an interview , now i want to implement it practically to widen my knowledge on the topic .

Comment: i want to implement a factory in spring using annotations , generallly we use serviceLocator interface to implement factory(with xml) , but how to do the same by using annotations

Answer (score 0):

I remember implementing support for this approach a few years ago, I believe inspired and using https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/combining-strategy-pattern-and-spring as the entry point to my utility library, use the following code snippets at your convenience:

**Strategy.java**

```
package ...

@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Strategy {

    Class<?> type();

    String[] profiles() default {};
}
```

**StrategyFactory.java**

```
package ...

public class StrategyFactory {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( StrategyFactory.class );

    private Map<Class<?>, Strategy> strategiesCache = new HashMap<Class<?>, Strategy>();

    private String[] packages;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (this.packages != null) {
            Set<Class<?>> annotatedClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
            for (String pack : this.packages) {
                Reflections reflections = new Reflections( pack );
                annotatedClasses.addAll( reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith( Strategy.class ) );
            }
            this.sanityCheck( annotatedClasses );
        }
    }

    public <T> T getStrategy(Class<T> strategyClass) {
        return this.getStrategy( strategyClass, null );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getStrategy(Class<T> strategyClass, String currentProfile) {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) this.findStrategyMatchingProfile( strategyClass, currentProfile );
        if (clazz == null) {
            throw new StrategyNotFoundException( String.format( "No strategies found of type '%s', are the strategies marked with @Strategy?", strategyClass.getName() ) );
        }
        try {
            return (T) clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw ExceptionUtils.rethrowAs( e, StrategyException.class );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks to make sure there is only one strategy of each type(Interface) annotated for each profile Will throw an exception on startup if multiple strategies are mapped to the same profile.
     * @param annotatedClasses a list of classes
     */
    private void sanityCheck(Set<Class<?>> annotatedClasses) {
        Set<String> usedStrategies = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Class<?> annotatedClass : annotatedClasses) {
            Strategy strategyAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation( annotatedClass, Strategy.class );
            if (!strategyAnnotation.type().isAssignableFrom( annotatedClass )) {
                throw new StrategyProfileViolationException( String.format( "'%s' should be assignable from '%s'", strategyAnnotation.type(), annotatedClass ) );
            }
            this.strategiesCache.put( annotatedClass, strategyAnnotation );

            if (this.isDefault( strategyAnnotation )) {
                this.ifNotExistAdd( strategyAnnotation.type(), "default", usedStrategies );
            } else {
                for (String profile : strategyAnnotation.profiles()) {
                    this.ifNotExistAdd( strategyAnnotation.type(), profile, usedStrategies );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ifNotExistAdd(Class<?> type, String profile, Set<String> usedStrategies) {
        String key = this.createKey( type, profile );
        if (usedStrategies.contains( key )) {
            throw new StrategyProfileViolationException( String.format( "There can only be a single strategy for each type, found multiple for type '%s' and profile '%s'", type, profile ) );
        }
        usedStrategies.add( key );
    }

    private String createKey(Class<?> type, String profile) {
        return String.format( "%s_%s", type, profile ).toLowerCase();
    }

    private boolean isDefault(Strategy strategyAnnotation) {
        return (strategyAnnotation.profiles().length == 0);
    }

    private Class<?> findStrategyMatchingProfile(Class<?> strategyClass, String currentProfile) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Strategy> strategyCacheEntry : this.strategiesCache.entrySet()) {
            Strategy strategyCacheEntryValue = strategyCacheEntry.getValue();
            if (strategyCacheEntryValue.type().equals( strategyClass )) {
                if (currentProfile != null) {
                    for (String profile : strategyCacheEntryValue.profiles()) {
                        if (currentProfile.equals( profile )) {
                            Class<?> result = strategyCacheEntry.getKey();
                            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                                LOG.debug( String.format( "Found strategy [strategy=%s, profile=%s, strategyImpl=%s]", strategyClass, currentProfile, result ) );
                            }
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (this.isDefault( strategyCacheEntryValue )) {
                    Class<?> defaultClass = strategyCacheEntry.getKey();
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        LOG.debug( String.format( "Found default strategy [strategy=%s, profile=%s, strategyImpl=%s]", strategyClass, currentProfile, defaultClass ) );
                    }
                    return defaultClass;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setPackages(String[] packages) {
        this.packages = packages;
    }
}
```

**StrategyException.java**

```
package ...

public class StrategyException extends RuntimeException {
...
}
```

**StrategyNotFoundException.java**

```
package ...

public class StrategyNotFoundException extends StrategyException {
...
}
```

**StrategyProfileViolationException.java**

```
package ...

public class StrategyProfileViolationException extends StrategyException {
...
}
```

**Usage without Spring**:

**NavigationStrategy.java**

```
package com.asimio.core.test.strategy.strategies.navigation;

public interface NavigationStrategy {

    public String naviateTo();
}
```

**FreeNavigationStrategy.java**

```
package com.asimio.core.test.strategy.strategies.navigation;

@Strategy(type = NavigationStrategy.class)
public class FreeNavigationStrategy implements NavigationStrategy {

    public String naviateTo() {
        return "free";
    }
}
```

**LimitedPremiumNavigationStrategy.java**

```
package com.asimio.core.test.strategy.strategies.navigation;

@Strategy(type = NavigationStrategy.class, profiles = { "limited", "premium" })
public class LimitedPremiumNavigationStrategy implements NavigationStrategy {

    public String naviateTo() {
        return "limited+premium";
    }
}
```

Then

```
...
StrategyFactory factory = new StrategyFactory();
factory.setPackages( new String[] { "com.asimio.core.test.strategy.strategies.navigation" } );
this.factory.init();

NavigationStrategy ns = this.factory.getStrategy( NavigationStrategy.class );
String result = ns.naviateTo();
Assert.assertThat( "free", Matchers.is( result ) );
...
Or
...
String result = factory.getStrategy( NavigationStrategy.class, "limited" ).naviateTo();
Assert.assertThat( "limited+premium", Matchers.is( result ) );
...
```

**Usage with Spring**:

**Spring context file**:

```
<bean id="strategyFactory" class="com.asimio.core.strategy.StrategyFactory">
    <property name="packages">
        <list>
            <value>com.asimio.jobs.feed.impl</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**IFeedProcessor.java**

```
package ...

public interface IFeedProcessor {

    void runBatch(String file);
}
```

**CsvRentalsFeedProcessor.java**

```
package ...

@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
@Strategy(type = IFeedProcessor.class, profiles = { "csv" })
public class CsvRentalsFeedProcessor implements IFeedProcessor, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private CsvRentalsBatchReporter batchReporter;
...
}
```

Then

```
...
IFeedProcessor feedProcessor = this.strategyFactory.getStrategy( IFeedProcessor.class, feedFileExt );
feedProcessor.runBatch( unzippedFeedDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + feedFileName );
...
```

Notice `CsvRentalsBatchReporter` is "injected" in `CsvRentalsFeedProcessor` bean (a Strategy implementation) but `StrategyFactory` instantiates the strategy implementation using `return (T) clazz.newInstance();`, so what's needed to make this object `Spring`-aware?
First `CsvRentalsFeedProcessor` to be annotated with `@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)` and when running the Java application this argument is needed in the java command: `-javaagent:<path to spring-agent-${spring.version}.jar>`

Comment: This is waaaay more complex than it needs to be. Just make all strategy Spring beans implement a Strategy interface, autowire a List<Strategy> in your factory, make sure that each strategy bean returns the type of car it allows managing, and you're good to go. And strategies are spring beans, thus benefitting from dependency injection, AOP, etc.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the Strategy annotation, StrategyFactory and Exception classes could packaged and reused in Spring and non Spring environment in a very clean and interesting way using annotations,  which btw was what Asish asked, "how can I have a factory using annotations ..."

Comment: @ootero - As much as i can understand  you have used reflections to create the bean from the name , that is what we can do in java to return an object on the basis of string passed , when interviewer asked me i also answered that we can use reflections , just that you are providing a very good implementation to it(with reflections and strategy design pattern) .... but i was looking for something without reflections ......something like implementation of  service locator with annotations